# How can I share resources between the different Eclipse projects, so as to avoid duplication?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 2 android applications that share 95% of their resources, layouts, strings etc. only a few jpg's are different.

**How can I share resources between the different Eclipse Android projects, so as to avoid resource duplication ?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eclipse provides 2 ways to do it,

1. Create a library project and include this library projects in two application projects
2. Create a Shared Source Folder, goto your project properties and in Source tab, you can link a folder which may be in any other project and include all files of those folder as a link, without duplicating them.

Comment: For more details on step 2 see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-WorkingWithExistingLayout4.htm and start at step 13.

Comment: How does one create a library project?

Comment: @Troyseph https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble figuring this out as well, and these answers didn't provide enough info for me to get code shared across projects (I'm running Eclipse Indigo SR2), so here's what I did:

Create a Java Project to consume the shared resources, say `SharedConsumer`
Create a Java Project that contains the shared resources, say `SharedResources`
Open Project Properties for `SharedConsumer`, navigate to Java Build Path, Projects tab
Click Add... and select `SharedResources`.

Resources within `SharedResources` are now all accessible to `SharedConsumer` as if they were within `SharedConsumer`.

Comment: I have done this and yet it still doesn't seem to work, my `SharedConsumer` source still complains it cannot see any of the classes or interfaces in the lib in `SharedResources`...

Answer (score 0):

Put all your common resources into a separate jar and use this in your separate projects.