# Eclipse Access Path from Parent Project

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

I have two projects in eclipse `A` and `B`. `A` depends upon `B`, but `B` does not depend upon `A`.

`B` has a utility method.

```
public class Utility {

  public static URL getImage(final String name) {
    return Utility.class.getResource("data" + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + name);
  }

}
```

I have a file in `A` under `data/images/`. When I call this utility method, it doesn't find the file. However, the method will find files which are in `B`. Is there a way I can get it to include files from `A`?

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I share resources between the different Eclipse projects, so as to avoid duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342901/3453226).

> Create a library project and include it in two application projects.